# I can't upload file using multer upload.fields() or multer.arrays in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, multer

Have been trying to upload files from different fields but the same form using multer but they are not displaying in front end that's my index page and the upload directory.

But anytime I `upload.single()` everything is working fine and even `upload.array()` is still not working.

Comment: This question was asked later than yours, but it might be of some help https://stackoverflow.com/q/61979897

Answer (score 0):

instead of `upload.array()` use `upload.any()`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in the HTML form where I was using the file input element.

For more info check: [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean#:%7E:text=enctype%3D%27multipart%2Fform%2Ddata,you%20must%20use%20this%20enctype.)